# How to enable undo for operators in sculpt mode?

Tags: python, add-on

I wrote a operator like that, And when I run this from object mode, everything is fine but if I run from sculpt mode, it cleans all the undo history and I ain't able to undo anything I did before.
Why is that?

```
class MaskDecimate(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "flow_tools.decimate"
    bl_label = "Mask Decimate"
    bl_description = ""
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    invoked = False
    
    ratio = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Ratio",
        description="How much to recuce",
        default=0.5,
        min = 0.0000001,
        max = 1.0
    )
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        if context.active_object:
            if not context.active_object.mode == "EDIT":
                return context.active_object.type == "MESH"
    
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.bm = bmesh.new()
        self.bm.from_mesh(context.active_object.data)
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        ob = context.active_object
        bm = self.bm
        bm.to_mesh(ob.data)
        
        layer = bm.verts.layers.paint_mask.verify()
        vg = ob.vertex_groups.new(name = "paint_vertex_group_mask")
        vg.add([v.index for v in bm.verts], 1.0, "REPLACE")
        
        for vert in bm.verts:
            mask_val = vert[layer]
            vg.add([vert.index], 1 - mask_val, "REPLACE")
        
        md = ob.modifiers.new(type="DECIMATE", name="Decmater")
        md.ratio = self.ratio
        md.vertex_group = vg.name
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=md.name)
        
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(ob.data)
        layer = bm.verts.layers.paint_mask.verify()
        
        for vert in bm.verts:
            vert[layer] = 1 - vg.weight(vert.index)
        
        ob.vertex_groups.remove(vg)
        
        bm.to_mesh(ob.data)
        bm.free()
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

Comment: I've got the same issue with my addon for 2.92. Maybe this is a bug in sculpt mode.

Answer (score 1):

As a variant of a solution. I could suggest adding history before all the code. But I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Blender's sculpt mode.

```
if context.mode != 'OBJECT':    
    bpy.ops.ed.undo_push()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a while and finally found a solution.

I created a custom operator that does the following:

1. change the mode to OBJECT
2. push an undo step
3. deselect all objects (might not need this step)

My implementation:

```
import bpy

class MPI_OT_ObjectMode(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Change to Object Mode and de-select all"""
    bl_idname = "object.mpi_object_mode"
    bl_label = "MPI Object Mode"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.ed.undo_push(message='Object Mode')
        if bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active == None:
            for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
                bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = o
                break
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')       

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Then I just call this operator within the execute() function in other operators that I want to make accessible in SCULPT mode like so:

```
def execute(self, context):
    bpy.ops.object.mpi_object_mode()
```